# Não consigo acessar a variavel filter na view nem no controller

Tags: mvc, filtro

Estou tentando criar um filtro por atualização usando MVC no php, porém não consigo acessar a variável que envio via get. Se alguém puder dar uma luz.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na url, tente `?filter=[amount]=500` (sem aspas simples).
Ou então, tente acesso com `$_GET['filter']["'amount'"]`.

Comment: Rapaz manhã inteira tentando resolver, com 3 minutos você me salva. Muito obrigado